# PHP mail sent, but its not received in inbox

Tags: php, mysql, email, html-email

I've written a php script which saves the data from the form in mysql database, and send an email after. The data is saved in the database, and the email is sent, but i'm not receiving it in inbox. I'm new to php and not sure what is causing this. Please help.

```
<?php 
 include ('regdb_conn.php');

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
$pAddress = $_POST['pAddress']; // required 
$lAddress = $_POST['lAddress']; // required 
$telno4 = $_POST['telno4']; // required 
$faxno4 = $_POST['faxno4']; // required
$email4 = $_POST['email4'];
$trade = $_POST['trade'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$noEmployee = $_POST['noEmployee'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$hr = $_POST['HR'];
$retainer_fee_1 = $_POST['retainer_fee_1'];
$retainer_fee_2 = $_POST['retainer_fee_2'];
$from_date = $_POST['from_date'];
$to_date = $_POST['to_date'];

$sql="INSERT INTO subscription(company_name,postal_address,location_address,
  telephone,fax,email,trade_union_workmen,nature_of_business,total_employee,
  details_newsletter,name_head_hr,retainer_fee_1,retainer_fee_2,from_date,to_date)
 VALUES('$companyname','$pAddress','$lAddress','$telno4','$faxno4','$email4',
     '$trade','$business','$noEmployee','$designation',                                   
'$hr','$retainer_fee_1','$retainer_fee_2','$from_date','$to_date')";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 if($result)    {
            echo "Data Successfully saved in database subscription!";
        }   
 else           {
            echo "ERROR, data was not saved or email was not sent";
        }


    $emailID = "suthan47@outlook.com";
    $subject = "New Subcription form submitted from. $companyname . through our website";

    $body = <<<EOD

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">Company Name: </td>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$companyname</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">Telephone No: </td>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$telno4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">Email: </td>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$email4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;" width="150">Fax No: </td>
                <td style="padding: 5px 10px;">$faxno4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>       
EOD;

    $headers = "From:" .$email4. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";

    mail($emailID, $subject, $body, $headers );
    echo "<h4>Thank you for sending us an enquiry. We will get back to you.</h4>";

} else {
    echo("Kindly use the form to submit the data!");
};
?>
```

Comment: checked in spam folder ?

Comment: also check if the email is actually sent `if( mail($emailID, $subject, $body, $headers ) ) {echo "sent";}`

Comment: @UserProg you are right.. I just thought it .

Comment: Where is the site hosted?  localhost? Online somewhere?

Comment: How do you know mail is sent ? you have to put a condition to check whether the mail is actually sent or not.

Comment: Verify your mail server log, if you don't get errors il PHP that only mean PHP successfully sent the email to the local mailserver, if the mailserver has an error, you will never know...

Comment: Your `\n` and `\r\n` are used inconsistently; this may not be the true cause, but I would fix it to the latter anyway.

Comment: @shatheesh, yes I checked the spam folder, no mails there.

Comment: @UserProg, yes, i used the if else condition and it'ssending, but not received in inbox

Comment: @zipzit, its not in localhost. its hosted online..using cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
if(mail($emailID, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    echo "<h4>Thank you for sending us an enquiry. We will get back to you.</h4>";
}
else{
    echo "<h4>Mail sending fail.</h4>";
}
```

Comment: i've used the if else conditon, the email is sent, but not received in my inbox

Answer (score -2):

```
    Try using \n instead of \r\n.

       OR

    you could use the PHP_EOL constant

       OR

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'To: Person <mail@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: My Name <myemail@address.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . "\r\n";
```